# How can I write an asynchronous pytest fixture which works in Python 3.5 and 3.6?

Tags: python, pytest, python-asyncio

I have a library which supports 3.5 and 3.6 and uses `asyncio` extensively. I'd like to have asynchronous fixtures which work in both 3.5 and 3.6, but this is proving difficult. The best approach I've found so far is to write my own fixture decorator to work around the differences in 3.5 and 3.6. The library basically fetches a data-driven coroutine chain from an external source. I'd like to test the coroutine chains produced.

My fixture and test look like this (and work in 3.5):

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
test_my_coroutine(coroutine):
    coroutine = await coroutine
    assert await coroutine() == 'expected result'

@pytest.fixture
async def coroutine():
    return await load_dynamic_coroutine()
```

Note that I must `await` the coroutine within the test when using 3.5. In 3.6 though, pytest evaluates the coroutine before passing it to the test. Thus, the await is no longer require and produces an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the coroutine from the fixture.

```
@pytest.fixture
def coroutine():
    async def _inner():
        return await load_dynamic_coroutine()
    return _inner
```

Comment: Hmmm... but, that still means i need to `await coroutine` in my test, which is not what I want.

Comment: @matthewatabet can you explain what you want a bit better? I am trying to use async fixtures myself